# Spring boot + Spring security logout gets redirected to login

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, logout

So in my Spring boot RESTful API my `/logout` mapping gets redirected to `/login`.

I already googled this problem and found a solution, but I do not know how to implement it with my code.

**My WebSecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class
WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {//provides security for endpoints

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    private final AccountService accountService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()//So we can send post requests without being rejected(if we using form based indication we want to enable this)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/authenticate")
                .permitAll()//any request that goes trough that end point we want to allow.
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.cors();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }
```

This does not work, so I tried to do it like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()//So we can send post requests without being rejected(if we using form based indication we want to enable this)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/authenticate")
            .permitAll()//any request that goes trough that end point we want to allow.
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and().addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.cors();

}
```

But this also does not work.

I know this piece of code :

```
.and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
```

Should fix my problem but it does not. Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want? Where do you want to redireted to?

Comment: A logout screen. It does not logout right now.

Comment: It does logout. By default the logout redirects to login page. That is okay. If you want to redirect to another page you have to change the `logoutSuccessUrl` URL.